# Could not find installation path for: apcu valet

Tags: pecl, laravel-valet, valet

I set up valet pro with composer, however, the site threw an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I tried to run valet install and it failed due to valet not finding installation path for pecl. How can I fix this?

```
[nginx] Stopping
[valet-php@7.2] Stopping
[valet-php@7.3] Stopping
[valet-php@7.4] Stopping
[mysql@5.7] Stopping
[redis] Stopping
[devtools] Installing tools
[devtools] wp-cli already installed
[devtools] pv already installed
[devtools] geoip already installed
[devtools] zlib already installed
[binaries] Installing binaries
[BREW TAP] henkrehorst/php already installed
[PECL] Updating PECL channel: pecl.php.net
[PECL] Installing extensions

In Pecl.php line 146:

Could not find installation path for: apcu

Could not download from "https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu-5.1.17.tgz", cannot download "pecl/apcu" (Connection to `ssl://pecl.php.
net:443' failed: )
Error: cannot download "pecl/apcu"
Download failed
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that `extension="apcu.so"` shows double times in your ***php.ini***. So first remove one.

And then run below commands:

```
pecl config-set preferred_state beta
pecl install geoip
```

I had the same issue and it fixed!